# How to change date format from string (24 Jun 2020) to Date 24-06-2020 in spark sql?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have a column with string values like '24 Jun 2020' i want to cast it as date type.

Is there a way to specify the format of input and output date format while casting from string to date type.

Answer (score 2):

Spark date format is **`yyyy-MM-dd`** you can use either **`to_date,to_timestamp,from_unixtime + unix_timestamp`** functions to change your string to date.

**`Example:`**

```
df.show()
#+-----------+
#|         dt|
#+-----------+
#|24 Jun 2020|
#+-----------+

#using to_date function
df.withColumn("new_format", to_date(col("dt"),'dd MMM yyyy')).show()

#using to_timestamp function
df.withColumn("new_format", to_timestamp(col("dt"),'dd MMM yyyy').cast("date")).show()
#+-----------+----------+
#|         dt|new_format|
#+-----------+----------+
#|24 Jun 2020|2020-06-24|
#+-----------+----------+

df.withColumn("new_format", to_date(col("dt"),'dd MMM yyyy')).printSchema()
#root
# |-- dt: string (nullable = true)
# |-- new_format: date (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 0):

The default date format for date is `yyyy-MM-dd` -

```scala
val df1 = Seq("24 Jun 2020").toDF("dateStringType")
    df1.show(false)
    /**
      * +--------------+
      * |dateStringType|
      * +--------------+
      * |24 Jun 2020   |
      * +--------------+
      */

    // default date format is "yyyy-MM-dd"
    df1.withColumn("dateDateType", to_date($"dateStringType", "dd MMM yyyy"))
      .show(false)
    /**
      * +--------------+------------+
      * |dateStringType|dateDateType|
      * +--------------+------------+
      * |24 Jun 2020   |2020-06-24  |
      * +--------------+------------+
      */

      // Use date_format to change the default date_format to "dd-MM-yyyy"
    df1.withColumn("changDefaultFormat", date_format(to_date($"dateStringType", "dd MMM yyyy"), "dd-MM-yyyy"))
      .show(false)
    /**
      * +--------------+------------------+
      * |dateStringType|changDefaultFormat|
      * +--------------+------------------+
      * |24 Jun 2020   |24-06-2020        |
      * +--------------+------------------+
      */
```

Comment: You can use any answer by the way